# Detecting sheet change, clearing the sheet giving an overflow

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Worksheet_Change` event, currently at the `Sheet Module Level`. The problem is that I want to be able to clear this sheet at times. However, when I clear my sheet I get an overflow:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'This is the line causing the problem because clearing the whole sheet causes the count to be massive
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target = Range("A4") Then
            If InStr(LCase(Target.Value), "loaded") <> 0 Then
                Range("A5").FormulaArray = "=My_Function(R[-1]C)"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

I press a button and the sheet is cleared (*clears existing array formula data*), I then paste in a formula to the sheet and call the formula. The formula returns data back to the excel cache and changes the cell containing this formula (A4) to a string saying "loaded". When I detect a cell change with value "loaded" I then do the equivalent on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an array formula function below, to display the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using xl2007+?

The `Target.Cells.Count` is a `Long` value and hence when you select the entire worksheet the `.Count` is too small to hold the result.

Replace line

```
If Target.Count = 1 Then
```

with

```
If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
```

You might also want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) since you are using `Worksheet_Change`

**EDIT**:

Two other things

**1)**

You can also replace this line

```
If Target = Range("A4") Then
```

with

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then
```

**2)**

This line

```
If InStr(LCase(Target.Value), "loaded") <> 0 Then
```

can also be written as

```
If InStr(1, Target.Value, "loaded", vbTextCompare) Then
```