# VB if cell is in range Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I made a VB makro in Excel to execute something if the cell is in a given range but when I execute it it gives me an error and I don't see why.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim isect As Boolean
isect = Application.Intersect(Selection, Range("D11:D35"))
If isect Then
    If ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) - ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1) > 2.5 Then
        Range("A1:A1").Value = "ok"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

The error is:

```
Object variable or With block variable not set.
```

Comment: `If Not isect Is Nothing Then`  You should also account for the fact that `Target` is not always a single cell: it can be a multiple-cell range...

Comment: You are getting that problem because your code tries to go into a loop because of `Range("A1:A1").Value = "ok"`. I would recommend seeing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640 Also Change `Selection` to `Target` EDIT: Also Tim has a valid point that `Target is not always a single cell` So you will have to account for that as well..

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks mate with `If Not isect Is Nothing Then` it works like a charm how can I accept your answer?

Comment: @SiddharthRout you're right excel just crashed.. what else could I use than WorkSheet_Change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first 3 lines into:

```
Dim isect As Range
Set isect = Application.Intersect(Selection, Range("D11:D35"))
If Not isect Is Nothing Then
```

but check also comment from @Siddharth about looping which is very important here.

Comment: damn you're right what else could I use than WorkSheet_Change?

Comment: just refer to [that idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13861640/2143262) by @Siddharth

Answer (score 0):

Another way without using a `Boolean Variable` / `Selection` (Also Incorporating Tim's suggestion as well)...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
        MsgBox "More than 1 cell ws changed"
    Else
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D11:D35")) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value - Target.Offset(-1, 1).Value > 2.5 Then
                Range("A1").Value = "ok"
            End If
        End If
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Note: Why `.CountLarge`? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771829/detecting-sheet-change-clearing-the-sheet-giving-an-overflow)